# How to pass the current index iteration inside a select new MyObject

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iteration

This is my code:

```
infoGraphic.chartData = (from x in db.MyDataSource
                         group x by x.Data.Value.Year into g
                         select new MyObject
                         {
                             index = "", // here I need a string such as "index is:" + index
                             counter = g.Count()
                         });
```

I need the current `index` iteration inside the `select new`. Where do I pass it?

**EDIT** - My current query:

```
var test = db.MyData
            .GroupBy(item => item.Data.Value.Year)
            .Select((item, index ) => new ChartData()
            {
                index = ((double)(3 + index ) / 10).ToString(),
                value = item.Count().ToString(),
                fill = index.ToString(),
                label = item.First().Data.Value.Year.ToString(),
            }).ToList();

public class ChartData
{
    public string index { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string fill { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `IEnumerable` extension methods, I think the syntax is more straightforward.
You need the 2nd overload, that receives the `IEnumerable` item and the index.

```
infoGraphic.chartData.Select((item, index) => {
   //what you want to do here
});
```

You want to apply grouping on your chartData, and afterwards select a subset / generate a projection on the resulting data ?

your solution should look like:

```
infoGraphic.chartData
    .GroupBy(...)
    .Select((item, index) => {
      //what you want to do here
});
```

abstracting the dataSource as x:

```
x.GroupBy(item => item.Data.Value.Year)
 .Select((item, index) => new { index = index, counter = item.Count() });
```

As a follow up to your new question...
here is a simple working scenario with a custom type (like your ChartData):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> data = new List<int> { 1, 872, -7, 271 ,-3, 7123, -721, -67, 68 ,15 };

        IEnumerable<A> result = data
            .GroupBy(key => Math.Sign(key))
            .Select((item, index) => new A { groupCount = item.Count(), str = item.Where(i => Math.Sign(i) > 0).Count() == 0 ? "negative" : "positive" });

        foreach(A a in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
}

public class A
{
    public int groupCount;
    public string str;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Group Count: [{0}], String: [{1}].", groupCount, str);
    }
}

/* Output:
*  -------
*  Group Count: [6], String: positive
*  Group Count: [4], String: negative
*/
```

**Important**: Make sure the data type you are to use the extension methods is of type IEnumerable (inherits IEnumerable), otherwise you will not find this Select overload my solution is talking about, exposed.

Comment: But I need group b into g, because in the object I need `g.Count()` for example.. How do you do this with Lambda expression?

Comment: You have a GroupBy extension method as well.

Comment: Yes. But the counter must go inside my ChartData object, for each group by. Looks the updated example.. g.Count()

Comment: Now if I use `.Select((item, index) => new ChartData() { }` it says `Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Select'.`

Comment: ChartData is a type you defined ?

Comment: Yes. Check the question, I've updated with the Class.

Comment: Was called `MyObject`, now I've change its name.

Comment: I've just added a complete working scenario, let me know.

Comment: It's the same of mine, but I got `Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Select'` :(

Comment: We have to find what's different between my and your codes.

Comment: Please post the alternative solution you are trying as I suggested - with extension methods...

Comment: Here you go: check the original topic, I've added my actual LINQ expression.

Comment: remove the parenthesis in "new ChartData() {...}" leaving it like "new ChartData {...}"

Comment: what is the type of MyData ? I'm affraid it is not an IEnumerable<T> ?

Comment: `System.Data.Linq.Table<MyObject>`. But seems that if I use `.AsEnumerable()` before the `.Select` it works as well. I don't understand why :)

Comment: Bingo, because you need that to make it an IEnumerable! If you do not make it an IEnumerable, it indeed will not have the Select overload that is exposed in the extension methods of IEnumerable<> ! Are we good now ? :) We are talking about this overload: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx . So unless your data is not of type IEnumerable, it will not have this Select overload exposed...

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

`let currIndex = collection.IndexOf(collectionItem)`

Your code would then become:

```
infoGraphic.chartData =

(from x in db.MyDataSource group x by x.Data.Value.Year into g

                         // Get Iterator Index Here
                         let currIndex = db.MyDataSource.IndexOf(x)

                         select new MyObject
                         {index = currIndex.ToString(), // Your Iterator Index
counter = g.Count()
                         });
```